# How to Implement Cut,Copy and Paste functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an visual Tree in which I have to apply Cut,Copy and paste functions to cut the vertex,copy the vertex and paste it.
I want the code to work in IE.
Could someone help me in code for cut,copy and paste in java script.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Read more on [Clipboard API and events](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/)

```
document.addEventListener('beforecopy', function(e){
    if(weHaveDataToCopy()){ // use your web app's internal logic to determine if something can be copied
        e.preventDefault(); // enable copy UI and events
    }
});

document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello, world!');
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', '<b>Hello, world!</b>');
    e.preventDefault(); // We want our data, not data from any selection, to be written to the clipboard
});

document.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
    if(e.clipboardData.types.indexOf('text/html') > -1){
        processDataFromClipboard(e.clipboardData.getData('text/html'));
        e.preventDefault(); // We are already handling the data from the clipboard, we do not want it inserted into the document
    }
});
```

[good reading](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands)